# Align two columns in center position in Vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

why my code can't be on the center even I tried to change it to justify-center and align-center?

```
 <main class="align-center">
  <v-row class="no-gutters" style="border: 3px solid green">
    <v-col>
      <v-row class="no-gutters">
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-card color="#fdf6f1" raised>
            <v-list shaped>
              .....
            </v-list>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="5">
          <v-card color="#fdf6f1" raised>
           .....
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</main>
```

This is what my code does to my two columns

[image: sc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mx-auto` on the outer `v-col`...

```
<main class="align-center">
  <v-row class="no-gutters" style="border: 3px solid green">
    <v-col class="mx-auto">
      <v-row class="no-gutters">
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-card color="#fdf6f1" raised>
            <v-list shaped>
              .....
            </v-list>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="5">
          <v-card color="#fdf6f1" raised>
           .....
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</main>
```